# Boost library missing at runtime (Can compile. Can't run)

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries

This is a pretty entry level question but I just can't seem to find any relevant answers.

I can compile [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html) no problem using the following command:

```
g++ client.cpp -o client -lboost_system -lpthread
```

When I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
./client 
./client: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this file exists: /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Wrong version installed? `libboost_system.so.1.58.0` specifies a version, and your `/usr/local/lib/` file does not.

Comment: You compile `client` but you run `./cilent`. I'd check this too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I didn't get a chance to test your answers. Upgraded to ubuntu 15.04 while troubleshooting another unrelated problem which happened to fix this problem aswell.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path where to find the shared object, the command  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path where shared object is will do it. I guess file is somewhere otherwise link would fail.

Answer (score -1):

It should be some linking error,

Try to compile it and create the .o file first.

g++ -C .cpp  // here you need to mention the includes from library. -I

And then create the executable,

g++ -O  // here you need to mention the path of the library. -l

Incase your prog is correct, it will create the exe else it will show you the error. Incase of linking error, try to include the .h and lib path correctly in the program.